# Set up Selenium ChromeDriver in Java for remote testing on Mac

Tags: java, google-chrome, webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

I'm trying to create a project in eclipse/java for selenium testing.

I'm doing this on a windows machine, which is also my hub for the selenium grid.

I want to run my tests on a remote machine which is mac.

In my project, when I set the webdriver like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chromeDriver.driver",
                    "C:\\SeleniumGrid\\chromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe"
```

that path should be pointing to the chromedriver on my remote/mac, right?

The mac already had chrome installed. I found the chromedriver on that machine here: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

But when I set it this way:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chromeDriver.driver",
            "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.MAC);
    cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    newDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
            "http://999.999.9.99:9999/wd/hub"), cap);
```

I get a null pointer exception on this line:

```
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Sorry, I'm new to selenium. Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Edit: here's the stacktrace

```
[TestNG] Running:

[ThreadUtil] Starting executor timeOut:2147483647ms workers:1 threadPoolSize:3
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp("chrome")
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at selenium.helper.WebUtils.setUpRemoteDriver(WebUtils.java:74)
    at selenium.testNG.TestNikeCareerSearch.setUp(TestNikeCareerSearch.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$0(SuiteRunner.java:333)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace. Moreover why \\ in path? Try using `/` only

Comment: @Smit the "\\" is because this page: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
led me to find the chromedriver at that location with single "\" but in Eclipse, it gave an error "invalid escape sequence" until I added the additional "\"s

Comment: I've not tried to run it remotely, but have you tried to put your chrome driver in a folder which is defined within the PATH? without settting the webdriver.chromeDriver.driver

Comment: @KirillKulakov I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you share an example of what your alternative way might look like?

Comment: As far as I remember you can put the ChromeDriver in a folder which is defined as PATH folder (google it), I'm not sure how it works on mac, but when I put the ChromeDriver within my PATH folder, I had just to create the ChromeDriver Object without any configuration in my code

Comment: @user1988594 May be this can help you [http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers]. I never run remote webdriver on mac so cant exactly tell you.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chromeDriver.driver",
"C:\\SeleniumGrid\\chromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe")
```

will run on your hub or the machine where your code is residing. The property therefore will be set on that machine and not on the remote.

You can add the statement `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="pathtochromedriverinnode"` while starting the webdriver node in mac machine. Something like this:

```
java -jar seleniumserver.jar -role wd -hub http://hubip:port/grid/register -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="pathtochromedriverinnode"
```